# Incorrect Category Name showing on WP single post

Tags: php, wordpress

I am editing a WP site built years ago for my client by another developer, who we aren't in touch with.

On the single post pages, there is a heading that displays the category name. For the posts of one of the categories, it is showing the name of the parent category, not the subcategory , for some reason. There are two categories with the same parents ("News" and "Events") – "Events" displays correctly, "News" does not.

The code to display the category name looks like this:

```
<h2 class="section_header"> 
    <?php
    $category = get_the_category();
    echo $category[0]->cat_name;
    ?>
</h2>
```

[Here is an example](http://www.sechc.org/en/happenings/news/accepting-new-patients/).
As you can see in the address bar, this post is categorized under "news", yet it is displaying the parent category ("happenings") in the heading.

As a comparison, you can look at [this post](http://www.sechc.org/en/happenings/events/breast-cancer-prevention-makes-a-difference/) which is in the category "events", whose parent is also "happenings", yet it displays the correct category title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking off which categories to file a post under, it is unnecessary to check off the parent. Un-checking the parent category from the post makes just the subcategory name display.